# MATLAB How to extract the functions for the envelopes?

Tags: matlab, datatable, signals, envelope

I programmed this:

```matlab
%plot envelope of a signal
%________________________________

%load('y-data')
load('ungedaempft.mat','t','s');
envelope(ungedaempft.s,17,'peak');
```

**datatypes (all imported in workspace):**
.mat file: 400x2 table
variables `s` and `t`: 400x1 double (imported as column vector in workspace)
`t` = x-axis value
`s` = y-axis value

[that's how the .mat 400x2 table looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PVT8.png)

How can I find out the function for the envelope in the sense of getting envelope(t)= ... in the command window?

I tried the command

```
"yupper =" and "ylower ="
```

in the command window to get the function Upper and lower signal envelopes as vectors/matrices≠functions, but it didn't work even if I change my initial code to

```
%load('y-data')  
load('ungedaempft.mat','t','s');  
[yupper,ylower] = envelope(ungedaempft.s,17,'peak');
```

even if I use the command `"supper ="` because y=s, no vector/matrix is returned. Would be very grateful for further help!

I get the errors:

```
Warning: Variable 't' not found. 
> In newenvelope (line 5) 
Warning: Variable 's' not found. 
> In newenvelope (line 5) Insufficient number of outputs from right hand side of equal sign to satisfy assignment. 
Error in newenvelope (line 9) [yupper,ylower] = envelope(ungedaempft.s,17,'peak');
```

& when I type the command to extract the function of the upper envelope, I receive the following error:

```
yupper = ↑ Error: Invalid expression. Check for missing or extra characters.
```

& couldn't find anything in the documentation, so I don't know how to proceed would be happy for your help!